# Wrapping methods without Decorator Pattern or AOP

Tags: java, solid, decorator, aspect-oriented

I have a `Dao` interface which doesn't have any methods defined.

Then I have multiple classes which implement this interface, like `PetDao` and `HouseDao`.

For some of the implementation classes, and some of their methods, I need to do an operation.

Let's say this operation is defined in the `Operation` class, and the method is `doOperation()`.

`PetDao` has several methods: `Pet selectPet(int petId)`, `void insertPet(PetDto pet)`, and I only want to call `doOperation()` for `insertPet`.

`HouseDao` has several methods: `House selectHouse(int houseId)`, `void deleteHouse(int houseId)`, and I only want to call `doOperation()` for `deleteHouse`.

I cannot modify the Dao interface. Neither of these classes are instantiated manually, they are all injected.

I could change `PetDao` and `HouseDao` code to statically call `doOperation()`. But this would mean that the Dao classes would have another responsibility than the originally intended, and that I would have a big impact on the source code (there are multiple Daos with multiple methods that I need to track).

I cannot use the Decorator Pattern because `Dao` interface does not have any methods.

Are there other options, besides AOP, to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new interface with your `doOperation` method in it, and have each DTO implement that interface?

Comment: `But this would mean that the Dao classes would have another responsibility than the originally intended` -- I'm not particularly concerned about this arbitrary distinction, if your proposed solution actually solves the problem you are having in a reasonably good way.

Comment: Your question is missing some crucial information. E.g.: "Dao interface does not have any methods" - why? "I have multiple classes which implement this interface" - why do they implement it? "I cannot modify the Dao interface." - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting a class isn't really a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.

The new logic is encapsulated in your Operation class, that's it's responsibility.  Calling a dependency doesn't really change what this class responsibile for.

Something like the below isn't really changing the responsibilities of your DAO class.

(forgive the C# syntax)

```
public class HouseDao:IDao
{
   public HouseDao(Operation myOperation)
   {
      <snip>
      operation = myOperation;
   }

    <snip>

   public void deleteHouse(int houseId)
   {
      //dostuff
      operation.doOperation()   
   }
}
```

All that said, if you really need an alternative, implementing this as a Visitor (https://www.baeldung.com/java-visitor-pattern) may be more along the lines of what you want.